# Does Cloud Composer have failover?

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I've read the Cloud Composer overview (https://cloud.google.com/composer/) and documentation (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/).

It doesn't seem to mention failover.
I'm guessing it does, since it runs on Kubernetes cluster.  Does it?

By failover I mean if the airflow webserver or scheduler stops for some reason, does it get started automatically again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since Cloud Composer is built on Google Kubernetes Engine, it benefits from all the fault tolerance of any other service running on Kubernetes Engine. Pod and machine failures are automatically healed.